# does enum fields have default values in c language

Tags: c

I'm reading a c code somewhere, I found this structure

```
typedef enum
{
  SPIIP_0,
  SPIIP_1,
  NUMBER_OF_SPIIP,
  ERROR_SPIIP
}SPIIP_ID_E;
```

and somewhere else in my code I found statemment : `if(IP>NUMBER_OF_SPIIP)`
but `NUMBER_OF_SPIIP` value is declared nowhere

my quesion is : deos enum type define value to it's elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. As per `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.2.2, **Enumeration specifiers**, paragraph 3, (*emphasis mine*)

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.<sup>127)</sup> An enumerator with `=` defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression. **If the first enumerator has no `=`, the value of its enumeration constant is `0`. Each subsequent enumerator with no `=` defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by adding `1` to the value of the previous enumeration constant.** (The use of enumerators with
>   = may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.) The enumerators of an enumeration are also known as its members.

So, in your case, `NUMBER_OF_SPIIP` holds a value of `2`.